# JSX files in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, create-react-app

Just wondering how create-react-app uses .js files instead of .jsx for jsx markup. Is it because of the special webpack configuration?
Btw, where can I find the webpack and babel configuration of my project created with create-react-app?

Comment: [`.jsx` works out of the box with create react app. Just restart the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56509136/4970442).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing special about the file extensions; it's just a matter of what's being run through Babel. For example:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:    /\.jsx?$/, 
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader:  'babel',
        query:   {
          presets: [
            'react',
            'es2015',
            'stage-0'
          ],
          plugins: [
            ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
          ]
        },
      }
```

This runs .js and .jsx through Babel with the React presets.

The Webpack and Babel configs are inside create-react-app.

You can eject them via:

`npm run eject` to get them "externalized", but only do it if you really want to.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#user-content-converting-to-a-custom-setup

Comment: Won't that pattern match `.js` or `.j`? Did you mean `/\.jsx?$/`?

Comment: @Aaron Hm. Yeah. In my defense I didn't write our webpack config :/

Comment: @DaveNewton, so you cannot make any changes to those Webpack & Babel configs without ejecting them?

Comment: @Horak Technically you could probably reach into `node_modules` and change it, but that seems like a truly bad idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I see; so standard protocol is to just eject, eh?